# Add new menu in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Sorry because my English not good! But I have a problem like this
1. I create a example using MVC3 to manage Menu Multil Level and Table Menu like this
- MenuWeb(MenuId,Name,Url,ParentId)
2. Function CreateMenu in Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CreateMenu()
        {
            ViewBag.MenuId = new SelectList(db.MenuWebs.ToList(), "MenuId", "Name");
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateMenu(MenuWeb menu)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.MenuWebs.InsertOnSubmit(menu);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("../admin/getallmenu");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

3. Form CreateMenu in CreateMenu.cshtml like this:

```
@model MyBlog.Models.MenuWeb
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateMenu";
}

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create menu</legend>

            <div class="div-lable">
                Menu Parent:
            </div>
            <div class="div-editor">
                @Html.DropDownList("MenuId")
            </div>
            <div class="div-lable">
                Name:
            </div>
            <div class="div-editor">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="div-lable">
                Url Redirect:
            </div>
            <div class="div-editor">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UrlRedirect)
            </div>
            <div class="div-lable">
                Order:
            </div>
            <div class="div-editor">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ordes)
            </div>
            <div class="div-editor">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Menu" />
            </div>
            <div class="div-editor">
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to list", "getallmenu")
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

And in this example. I don't know to set MenuId from Dropdowlist into ParentId? I try submit but ParentId alway is null. Please help me! Thanks so murch.

Comment: Show us your MenuWeb model class.

Comment: I using LinQ. And in my Model Folder, I have only file MenuDb.dbml . I  haven't any class Entities in Model Folder

Comment: okay, in your designer.cs file find the class of "MenuWeb" and paste that code.

Comment: Thanks Kundan Singh Chouhan! 
You can see my code in link : http://www.mediafire.com/view/?ddgyvcvkyolv2z9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay change your code something like this :

**Controller**

---

Replace this

```
ViewBag.MenuId = new SelectList(db.MenuWebs.ToList(), "MenuId", "Name");
```

With

```
ViewBag.MenuIds = new SelectList(db.MenuWebs.ToList(), "MenuId", "Name");
```

**View**

---

Replace this

```
@Html.DropDownList("MenuId")
```

With

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentId, (SelectList)ViewBag.MenuIds)
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: I just clicked YES in 'was this post useful to you'. That right?

Comment: No there is a right sign showing in my anwer with up and down votes. Through up/down vote you can vote some one and by clicking on right it means that you have accepted that answer.